# client not reading from a private fifo

Tags: c, private, public, fifo

I have been working on this code where a client has to read from a server. The client will write 1 name and 3 values to the server and the server has to return that through a private fifo. the thing is, the client is not reading the private fifo from the server. I am expecting to get back the values the server creates. here is the code for both the client and server:

*edit: per suggestion on the comments, here is my inputs for both the client and server... on the server side, I typed "1" client so it receives 1 client. client: I typed any name (home lets say), then for the numbers 100, 150 and 200, the server side receives all of that, then the server is supposed to send the "memory address" of each through the private fifo. client does not get any of the memory addresses and just gets random negative numbers

Client:

```
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/stat.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <errno.h>
#include <fcntl.h>

struct values {
  int intVal0[1];
  int intVal1[1];
  int intVal2[1];
  int adss[7];
  int freeSp[1];
  };
struct strings {
  char strbuff[100];
  char privateFIFO[14];
  };

main (void)
{
  struct values val;
  struct strings strs;
  int fda;  // to write to server
  int fdb;  // to read response from server
  int clientID;
  char temp[14];
  memset(val.freeSp,0,1);
  memset(strs.strbuff,0,100); 
  memset(val.intVal0,0,1); 
  memset(val.intVal1,0,1);
  memset(val.intVal2,0,1);
  memset(val.adss,0,7); 
  memset(strs.privateFIFO,0,14); 

  clientID = getpid();
  sprintf(strs.privateFIFO, "FIFO_%d", clientID);
  printf("\nFIFO name is %s\n", strs.privateFIFO);

  if((fda=open("FIFO1", O_WRONLY))<0)
     printf("cant open fifo to write");

  printf("You have 3 segments inwhich to put your program.");
  printf("\nYou have a total of 2000mu.");
  printf("\nClient: Please enter the name of the program: ");
  scanf("%s", &strs.strbuff);
  strcpy(strs.strbuff, strs.strbuff);
  printf("\nClient: Please enter a how the amount of memory for segment 0: ");
  scanf("%d", &val.intVal0);
  while(val.intVal0[0] <= 0)//while loop to make sure segment 0 gets a value greater than 0
    {
       printf("Client: Please reenter an amount of memory that is 0 or higher for segment 0: ");
       scanf("%d", &val.intVal0);
    }   
  printf("Client: Please enter a how the amount of memory for segment 1: ");
  scanf("%d", &val.intVal1);
  while(val.intVal1[0] <= 0)//while loop to make sure segment 1 gets a value greater than 0
    {
       printf("Client: Please reenter an amount of memory that is 0 or higher for segment 1: ");
       scanf("%d", &val.intVal1);
    }
  printf("Client: Please enter a how the amount of memory for segment 2: ");
  scanf("%d", &val.intVal2);
  while(val.intVal2[0] <= 0)//while loop to make sure segment 2 gets a value greater than 0
    {
       printf("Client: Please reenter an amount of memory that is 0 or higher for segment 2: ");
       scanf("%d", &val.intVal2);
    }

  write(fda, &strs, sizeof(struct strings));
  write(fda, &val, sizeof(struct values));

  printf("\nClient: Got the values sent, now waiting for response\n ");
  if((fdb=open(strs.privateFIFO, O_RDONLY))<0)
     printf("\ncant open fifo to read");

  read(fdb, &val, sizeof(struct values));
  if (val.freeSp[0] >= 0 && val.freeSp[0] >= val.intVal0[0] && val.freeSp[0] >= val.intVal1[0] && 
    val.freeSp[0] >= val.intVal2[0])// if free space is greater than 0, prints what is below
    {  
          printf("\nClient: address of segment 0: %d - %d", val.adss[0], val.adss[1]);
          printf("\nClient: address of segment 1: %d - %d", val.adss[2], val.adss[3]);
          printf("\nClient: address of segment 2: %d - %d", val.adss[4], val.adss[5]);
          printf("\nClient: free space available: %d\n", val.freeSp[0]);
          printf ("\nall done!\n");
    }
   else// if free space is less than or equal to 0, prints below
    {
         printf("\nClient: No memory allocated because segment sizes are too big");
         printf ("\nall done!\n");
    }
  close(fda);
  close(fdb);



}
```

client output:

```
Client: Please enter the name of the program: home

Client: Please enter a how the amount of memory for segment 0: 100
Client: Please enter a how the amount of memory for segment 1: 150
Client: Please enter a how the amount of memory for segment 2: 200

Client: Got the values sent, now waiting for response

cant open fifo to read
Client: address of segment 0: 0 - 134217728
Client: address of segment 1: -17028108 - -17701883
Client: address of segment 2: -18270303 - 134549970
Client: free space available: 134511872
```

server:

```
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/stat.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <errno.h>
#include <fcntl.h>

struct values {
  int intVal0[1];
  int intVal1[1];
  int intVal2[1];
  int adss[7];
  int freeSp[1];
  };

struct strings {
  char strbuff[100];
  char privateFIFO[14];
  };

main (void)
{
  struct values val;
  struct strings strs;
  int fda;  // to read from client
  int fdb;  // to write to client
  int finish;   // lets me know that client is done
  int i;    // because C needs this defined as int
  int n =0;  //counter for amount of clients 
  int m = 0;  //counter for addresses on server
  int mem = 2000; // set allocated memory
  int inputMemTot;// total amount of segmented memory from client
  int numClient; // input of number of clients
  int upkeep = 0; // keeps the last place of memory address 
  int adssOnSvr[100];  // array that keeps track of all client addresses, only on server
  char prgName[10][14];// array that will store program names

  memset(strs.strbuff,0,100); 
  memset(val.intVal0,0,1); 
  memset(val.intVal1,0,1);
  memset(val.intVal2,0,1);
  memset(val.freeSp,0,1);
  memset(val.adss,0,7); 
  memset(strs.privateFIFO,0,14);
  printf("\nServer: Please enter the name of clients: ");
  scanf("%d", &numClient);

  for( i = 0; i < numClient; i++)
  {
     if ((mkfifo("FIFO1",0666)<0 && errno != EEXIST))
     {
         perror("cant create FIFO1");
         exit(-1);
     }

     if((fda=open("FIFO1", O_RDONLY))<0)
         printf("cant open fifo to write");


     read(fda, &strs, sizeof(struct strings));
     read(fda, &val, sizeof(struct values));    //read the character
     memset(val.adss,0,7); 
     strcpy(strs.strbuff, strs.strbuff);
     strcpy(strs.privateFIFO, strs.privateFIFO);
     //strcpy(prgName[i][14], strs.strbuff);
     inputMemTot = val.intVal0[0] + val.intVal1[0] + val.intVal2[0];// adds up all segment sizes 
     val.freeSp[0] = mem - inputMemTot;// puts the value of free space into here
     printf("Server: just got the program name: %s", strs.strbuff);
     printf("\nServer: just got the size of segment0: %d", val.intVal0[0]);
     printf("\nServer: just got the size of segment1: %d", val.intVal1[0]);
     printf("\nServer: just got the size of segment2: %d\n", val.intVal2[0]);

     if(upkeep = 0)
     {
         val.adss[0] = 0;  // set address location for starting value of segment 0
         adssOnSvr[0] = 0;
     }
     else 
         val.adss[0] = upkeep;
     val.adss[1] = val.intVal0[0] - 1; // set address location for ending value of segment 0
     adssOnSvr[1 + m] = val.adss[1];
     val.adss[2] = val.intVal0[0]; // set address location for starting value of segment 1
     adssOnSvr[2 + m] = val.adss[2];
     val.adss[3] =  val.adss[2] + val.intVal1[0] - 1; // set address location for ending value of segment 1
     adssOnSvr[3 + m] = val.adss[3];
     val.adss[4] = val.adss[3] + 1; // set address location for starting value of segment 2
     adssOnSvr[4 + m] = val.adss[4];
     val.adss[5] =  val.adss[4] + val.intVal2[0];// set address location for ending value of segment 2
     adssOnSvr[5 + m] = val.adss[5];
     val.adss[6] = 0;
     upkeep = val.adss[5];
     m = m + 5;

     if ((mkfifo(strs.privateFIFO,0666)<0 && errno != EEXIST))
      {
         perror("cant create client fifo");
         exit(-1);
      }

     if((fdb=open(strs.privateFIFO, O_WRONLY))<0)
         printf("cant open %s to read", strs.privateFIFO);

     write(fdb, &val, sizeof(struct values)); 

     close(fda);
     close(fdb);
     unlink("FIFO1");
     unlink(strs.privateFIFO);
     /*if(i == numClient)
         break;*/
    }
  if (val.freeSp[0] >= 0)// if free space is greater than 0, prints what is below
    {  
      for(n = 0; n < numClient; n++)
      {
         m = 0;
         //printf("\nServer: Program %s", prgName[n][14]);
         if(n = 0)
             printf("\nServer: address of segment 0: %d - %d", adssOnSvr[0], adssOnSvr[1 + m]);
         else
             printf("\nServer: address of segment 0: %d - %d", adssOnSvr[0 + m], adssOnSvr[1 + m]);

         printf("\nServer: address of segment 1: %d - %d", adssOnSvr[2 + m], adssOnSvr[3 + m]);
         printf("\nServer: address of segment 2: %d - %d", adssOnSvr[4 + m], adssOnSvr[5 + m]);
         m = m + 5;
      }
      printf("\nServer: free space available: %d\n", val.freeSp[0]);

    }
  if(val.freeSp[0] <= 0)// if free space is less than or equal to 0, prints below
    {   
       printf("\nServer: Segment sizes are to big. No memory allocated.\n");

    }

   printf("\nServer: This says I am ready to close \n");
  /*close(fda);
  close(fdb);
  /*unlink("FIFO1");*/
}
```

server output:

```
Server: Please enter the name of clients: 1
Server: just got the program name: home
Server: just got the size of segment0: 100
Server: just got the size of segment1: 150
Server: just got the size of segment2: 200
```

this is where the server does nothing after that and I have to exit manually using control + c

Comment: Exactly what did you expect to happen and exactly what actually happens?

Comment: I am expecting that the values I send on the client, come back from the server. what is happening the client can't open the private fifo to read and it puts different values that are not the ones I sent

Comment: I said *exactly* - what did you type in to run both programs, what did you type into both programs (if anything), what does the client output, what does the server output?

Comment: ohh... on server side, I typed 1 client so it receives 1 client.

client: I typed any name (home lets say), then for the numbers 100, 150 and 200, 

the server side receives all of that, then the server is supposed to send the "memory address" of each through the private fifo. 

client does not get any of the memory addresses and just gets random negative numbers

Comment: So the client doesn't print "cant open fifo to read", so why did you say the client can't open the FIFO to read?

Comment: Also this information should be in the question, just like the code is in the question, not in the comments.

Comment: I managed to get that now, although the server seems to get 'stuck' and does not continue after printing the values gotten from the client. On the client side, the client continues to print those negative values after it prints "cant open fifo to read".

Comment: *editing the information from the comments into the question for future reference as well

Comment: I told you to say everything the server and client said, and you didn't say the client said "cant open fifo to read", which means the client didn't print it because you said everything it printed. Did the client print it or not?

Comment: the client prints, but not what is supposed to print. it needs to print on both the server and client side the same information (name: home, segment 0: 100, segment 1: 150 and segment 2:200 ), instead it prints large negative numbers that I will not type here due to lack of space after I get "cant open fifo to read". Server does not process anything after it reads segment 2. What the client prints is not what is on the server once it comes back. And thats why I state the client is not reading the private fifo properly. Am I explaining myself now?

Comment: "instead it prints large negative numbers that I will not type here due to lack of space" - I will ask again very specifically: *Copy-paste* what you see on the client's console and what you see on the server's console into the question. Format them as code blocks (even though they're not actually code, this just stops the formatting getting messed up).

Comment: *just added the console from both client and server to the code. I appreciate all the help, me and a friend have been working on the code for over a week

Comment: Okay, so the client can't open the FIFO to read. Your next job is to find out *why* the client can't open the FIFO to read. You might want to print out the FIFO name, and strerror(errno)

Comment: I went to check with my Teaching Assistant and she could not figure the error out. she double checked the code and apparently everything looks perfect. We found out that the FIFO is actually created but somehow the server is not printing even though the lines of code are perfectly fine.

Comment: Maybe that's because the client couldn't open the FIFO. Let me repeat what I just said: Your next job is to find out why the client can't open the FIFO to read. You might want to print out the FIFO name, and strerror(errno)